# Use case for foreground and background threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

In C# Threading, by default the new thread is a foreground thread.

But what is the use case of a background thread?

Also, on what does the main thread run -> on foreground or background thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the main difference between foreground and background threads is:

> Background threads are identical to foreground threads with one
>   exception: a background thread does not keep the managed execution
>   environment running. Once all foreground threads have been stopped in
>   a managed process (where the .exe file is a managed assembly), the
>   system stops all background threads and shuts down.

So, the use case for background threads are, tasks that should not prevent your process from terminating.

> If you use a thread to monitor an activity, such as a socket
>   connection, set its IsBackground property to true so that the thread
>   does not prevent your process from terminating.

Considering the difference, UI thread should be foreground so that it keeps the process running until UI shuts down. If it was a background thread, the process stopped running as soon as no other foreground thread was running.

**Edit:**

Since you can signal the foreground threads when process is supposed to terminate, I don't see any special use case that cannot be implemented using foreground threads only. Since those thread may need to be informed about termination to free resources or perform an action, manually signaling them (rather than relying on the fact that they will be terminated because there are background) could be a better choice. But making them background would be a "Just in case" thing, that if for some reason they doesn't get signaled, they do not prevent process from terminating.

Comment: any specific use case example.?

Comment: As I quoted in the answer a use case would be Activity Monitoring. Listening on a port for an incoming connection for example.

Comment: Is there any way to make the Pooled threads foreground or are they strictly always background threads? If so, then what do you think is their use case? Same as  Activity Monitoring, Listening on a port?

Comment: I don't get your point. You can do whatever you want with background thread pool threads, but they just don't prevent the process from terminating, that's all.